# SPFx adal acquire token renewal failed

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, angularjs, adal

I have created an angular-adal SPFx project, now when I'm trying to acquire the token. It always displays a message:

> Token renewal operation failed due to timeout

```
adal.acquireToken("Dynamic 365 API", (error, token)=>{

console.log("error");

});
```

**EDIT**

After using the inbuilt spfx `AadHttpClient`, the issue which I am Facing.

> Error: The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that
>   is not supported in the current environment.

**Code**

```
this.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient('https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/{ApplicationId}').then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
    client.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', AadHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<JSON> => {
      debugger;
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((responseJSON: JSON): void => {

      debugger;
      var claimsTable = this.domElement.getElementsByClassName("azFuncClaimsTable")[0];
      for (var key in responseJSON) {
        var trElement = document.createElement("tr");
        // trElement.innerHTML = `<td class="${styles.azFuncCell}">${key}</td><td class="${styles.azFuncCell}">${responseJSON[key]}</td>`;
        claimsTable.appendChild(trElement);
      }
    });
  });
```

**Line where error comes**

```
client.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', AadHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<JSON> => {
```

**Image Description**

[image: Error: The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment.]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, I recommend you to upgrade your solution to the latest SPFx 1.6 version and get rid of `adal.js` in your code. Read [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/SharePoint-Framework-v1.6-release-notes) more about the release and how to upgrade your solution.

Why I suggest moving to 1.6:

- `adal.js` inside SPFx has lots of caveats you should be aware of. You should implement everything by yourself, which might be error prone because of complexity
- SPFx 1.6 introduced new helper classes for such things as Azure AD authentication. Please read [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient) article to learn, how to send authenticated http requests to your API with SPFx 1.6. It's not surprise, that internally Microsoft uses `adal.js`, however they use patched version, which works smoothly

[This](https://www.vrdmn.com/2018/02/sharepoint-framework-calling-aad.html) great article by @Vardhaman Deshpande contains a very good sample on how to call Azure AD protected API hosted as Azure function with SPFx 1.6 features.

Comment: Can I call this API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`?

Comment: Sure, you can call it

Comment: Please! check my edits.

Comment: Since you need MS Graph, then please use [GraphClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph) which is even simpler. If you see "experimental feature", please follow [these](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2473#issuecomment-419212148) steps (comment) to resolve it

Comment: also please make your user and administrator and admin site collection, for that purpose follow these [steps](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2472#issuecomment-419213781)

Comment: No success, same issue. May I need to create any `c#` application first and then deploy it in `Azure`?

I just add `code` mention in question. Any `configuration` also need to add?

Comment: No, you don't have to create anything. I had a similar issue and resolved it with mentioned steps. That's strange. If you open a page https://yourtenanthere-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/settings.aspx Do you see any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83060/discussion-between-utkarsh-dubey-and-sergei-sergeev).

Comment: Can you please! rejoin chat room and help me. Thanks for the help.